# cannot 301 redirect urls that have a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

I can do this redirect:

Redirect 301 /donate.html http://domainname.org/donate.shtml

But this won't work:

Redirect 301 /donate/ http://domainname.org/donate.shtml

Why?

Answer (score 0):

**Because `Redirect` doesn't support regex.** Use `RedirectMatch` instead with optional trailing slash:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/donate/?$ http://domainname.org/donate.shtml
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, but that's a fail for some reason. Either with or without the redirectmatch,  http://domainname.org/donate// generates a 404 error; no redirect takes place :(

Comment: Where is this htaccess located?

Comment: "Where is this htaccess located?"

Hi Anubhava -- it's located in the root directory

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question?